Visual Studio 2019 does not open project's property page
In Visual Studio 2019 Pro, after a fresh installation, when choosing Project -> Properties, I'm getting the following error message:

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing several times. Same error.
Tried updating to latest version of 2019. Same error.
Tried uninstalling and installing all VS packages, including VisualBasic. Same error.
Tried uninstalling and installing VS 2022 Community. Same error...
When looking at ActivityLog.xml, found this:
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [VBPackage]Source: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors&apos; Description: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.VBPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.&#x000D;&#x000A;To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.&#x000D;&#x000A;Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.&#x000D;&#x000A;To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
<guid>{67909B06-91E9-4F3E-AB50-495046BE9A9A}</guid>



The 'VBPackage' package did not load correctly. Could not load file or assembly XXX.

I suspect some files of installed packages may be corrupted. For this issue, here are suggestions you can check to troubleshoot.
1.Please close Visual Studio, go to C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_XXXXXXXX folder and remove ComponentModelCache folder. Open VS and check again.
2.Did you install any third-party extensions? If yes, please disable them.You can also to run devenv /SafeMode to launch your VS to load your project to see if the issue persists.
3.What is the type of your project? Is this issue occurs when you open other types of project?
4.Repair your VS from VS Installer.
5.If above suggestions don't help, consider use InstallCleanup.exe to remove all installed instances then reinstall the latest version of VS2022.


I've deleted the .vs folder. I've delete the %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16_xxxx\ComponentModelCache and %appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0 folders. I've run in command prompt Devenv.exe /ResetSettings, Devenv.exe /ResetAddin and Devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs.
No extenstion installed. I'ts a clean VS installation.
It's a simple console project. Happens also with a service project.
I've tried repairing VS from VS installer, with no success.
I prefer using vs 2019.


I think it may be a problem with cache files, system environment, permissions, or limitations on the machine. Please check them one by one: 1.Please run VS as an administrator and load your project's property page. 2.please check if you have specialized anti-virus, app-blocker, or GPO phased permission software installed that maybe be blocking this process.3. Delete C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio folder.

No 3rd party anti-virus installed. No alteration to the GPO. Deleted the folder, run the VS as Administrator. No luck, same error message.

Did you use InstallCleanup.exe  tool to remove installed instances and reinstall VS 2019?

Yes, without any luck.

Close VS and try to run the following command. Here is a similar old ticket and some users reported it works for VS 2022.
devenv.exe /clearcache
devenv /updateconfiguration


I'm familiar with this ticket and tried those commands. Still getting the same error.

I don't have any better suggestions for now. If you don't mind, consider checking for Windows Updates, and the last step is to reinstall your  operating system.

Reinstalling the OS is reserved as a last resort. The VS 2019 was working fine until upgrading to VS 2022.

Reporting this issue on Visual Studio Forum may help. That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group.
